# DataFrame from variable and filtering data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` and want to extract 3 columns from it, but one of them is an input from the user. I made a list, but need it to be iterable so I can run a *For iteration*.
So far I made it through by making a dictionary with 2 of the columns making a list of each and zipping them... but I really need the 3 columns...

My code:

```
Data=pd.read_csv(----------)
selec=input("What month would you want to show?")
NewData=[(Data['Country']),(Data['City']),(Data[selec].astype('int64')]

#here I try to iterate:
iteration=[i for i in NewData if NewData[i]<=25] 
print (iteration)
*TypeError:list indices must be int ot slices, not Series*
```

My CSV is the following:

[image]

I want to be able to choose the month with the variable "selec" and filter the results of the month I've chosen... so the output for `selec="Feb"` would be:
[image]

I tried as well with `loc`/`iloc`, but not lucky at all (unhashable type:'list').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the below example for how you can:

- select specific columns from a `DataFrame` by providing a list of columns between the selection brackets ([link to tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-select-specific-columns-from-a-dataframe))
- select specific rows from a `DataFrame` by providing a condition between the selection brackets ([link to tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-filter-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe))
- iterate rows of a `DataFrame`, although I don't suppose you need it - if you'd like to keep working with the `DataFrame` after filtering it, it's better to use the method mentioned above (you won't have to put the rows back together, and it will likely be more performant because `pandas` is optimized for bulk operations)

```py
import pandas as pd

# this is just for testing, instead of pd.read_csv(...)
df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Country="Spain", City="Madrid", Jan="15", Feb="16", Mar="17", Apr="18", May=""),
    dict(Country="Spain", City="Galicia", Jan="1", Feb="2", Mar="3", Apr="4", May=""),
    dict(Country="France", City="Paris", Jan="0", Feb="2", Mar="3", Apr="4", May=""),
    dict(Country="Algeria", City="Argel", Jan="20", Feb="28", Mar="29", Apr="30", May=""),
])

print("---- Original df:")
print(df)

selec = "Feb"  # let's pretend this comes from input()

print("\n---- Just the 3 columns:")
df = df[["Country", "City", selec]]  # narrow down the df to just the 3 columns
df[selec] = df[selec].astype("int64")  # convert the selec column to proper type
print(df)

print("\n---- Filtered dataframe:")
df1 = df[df[selec] <= 25]
print(df1)

print("\n---- Iterated & filtered rows:")
for row in df.itertuples():
    # we could also use row[3] instead of getattr(...)
    if getattr(row, selec) <= 25:
        print(row)
```

Output:

```
---- Original df:
   Country     City Jan Feb Mar Apr May
0    Spain   Madrid  15  16  17  18
1    Spain  Galicia   1   2   3   4
2   France    Paris   0   2   3   4
3  Algeria    Argel  20  28  29  30

---- Just the 3 columns:
   Country     City  Feb
0    Spain   Madrid   16
1    Spain  Galicia    2
2   France    Paris    2
3  Algeria    Argel   28

---- Filtered dataframe:
  Country     City  Feb
0   Spain   Madrid   16
1   Spain  Galicia    2
2  France    Paris    2

---- Iterated & filtered dataframe:
Pandas(Index=0, Country='Spain', City='Madrid', Feb=16)
Pandas(Index=1, Country='Spain', City='Galicia', Feb=2)
Pandas(Index=2, Country='France', City='Paris', Feb=2)
```